# Examples of Native Apps Using Flash as the UI?

Tags: windows, apache-flex, flash

I'm considering using Flash as the UI of a native Windows app, for several reasons, but before I dive in and start building, I figured I'd poll the community to find out whether anyone's got any good examples of this particular approach out there today, just to prove the concept satisfactorily.

So I guess that's pretty much the question:  Anyone built one specifically?  Or better, anyone know of an app in relatively wide distribution that demonstrates the viability of this approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not looking for alternative approaches, incidentally; I realize there are many options, here.  What I'm looking for are examples of native apps (Windows or Mac) running Flash UIs.

Comment: You may already be working with this Air 2 feature.  A sample isn't much of a "good example", of course.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process_02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe's own Creative Suite supports Flash-based panels. In fact, I believe most of the panels in Flash CS4 are built with Flash. I am 100% certain that the library is made in Flash, and many of the other panels have the same look and feel which definitely isn't from the native OS.

When I worked on [Crystal Xcelsius](http://xcelsius.com/), it hosted Flash content in a native Windows app. The app allows users to build Flash dashboards using Excel data. The drawing area itself is a WYSIWYG view of the resulting output running on Flash Player. Property editing windows for each component are built with Flash too. They're skinned to look like Windows, I think, but there are a few tell-tale signs of the fact that they're Flash.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Josh.  That is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. ;)  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you build it in Flash, it's no longer going to be a native Windows app.

While Flash might look pretty, it's going to require users to at least install Flash player on their computer (which, in some corporate environments, is still not allowed).

Personally, I'd suggest checking out WPF. It's part of .NET and can produce some really REALLY great UIs.

Comment: Not entirely accurate anymore. AIR is different from Flash Player and allows users to perform more complex system-wide operations. AIR2 detects USB insertion/removal, links up to native applications, etc. Plus you have access to the file system for read/write. So it's a viable option, and if you can install the app you can install the runtime - any corporate setup that prohibits AIR will prohibit any other apps as well, presumably.

Comment: True, but AIR applications are developed using Flex (which is different than developing an entire UI in Flash). Poor interpretation on my part.

Comment: Actually you can deploy AIR from Flash as well as Flex - Adobe doesn't promote that as much as they perhaps should, but you can do AIR with Flash, Flex and JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build native windows/mac apps in Flash. What you CAN do is use AIR (Adobe Integrated Runtime) to build AIR applications which run on your desktop. These aren't quite native - they require the AIR Runtime in order to work, a bit like Java programs require a JRE.

Adobe has done a pretty good job, however, making the runtime download and installation fairly seamless. When you install your first AIR app it'll install the runtime if you don't have it.

After that, you have complete control over the look/feel of your app. If you want it to look like a native Windows app that's more or less up to you - if your design chops are up to the task you can simulate it pretty well. Most people, however, don't try - one reason being that AIR apps work on both mac and windows, though you could in theory tell it to emulate its host OS.

If you want an example of AIR apps, check out TweetDeck - it's probably the most widely used. Other than that, run a google search for the Adobe AIR Marketplace.

I hope that helped!

Comment: I'm not looking to build a native application IN Flash, I'm considering building a native application in C++ that hosts the Flash control.  (AIR is not an option.)  Just looking for comparable examples of this approach in the known universe. :)

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes a little more sense but I'm not sure I can help you. You might consider looking into Adobe's Alchemy - it's a mechanism by which C++ can compile into AS3 and I'm not sure if it works both ways (probably not) but it might give you a place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

One that comes to my mind is [TweetDeck](http://tweetdeck.com/). You can see more AIR applications at [Adobe AIR market-place](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.home&marketplaceid=1)